# How to display a decimal point answer in c#

Tags: c#, double, decimal

I want to equate 24/5 in my console and display the equation and answer on screen (answer = 4.8), I have written my code as:

```
int answer = 24 / 5; //declare answer
Console.WriteLine("24 / 5 = " + answer);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have tried using the variables decimal, double, float and int for answer but the console will always write the answer "4" and not "4.8".

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int answer = 24 / 5;
```

Everything above is `int`, how do you expect to get a decimal point ? even if you change the type of `answer` to `double` this would not solve the problem since `24 / 5` still returns an integer value.

To get a `double` value, atleast one of the operand should be of `double` type. Like:

```
double answer = (double) 24 / 5;
```

Or

```
double answer =  24d / 5;
```

Or

```
double answer = 24.0 / 5;
```

Or

```
double answer = 24 * (1.0) / 5;
```

Or modify/cast `5` to double.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `24 / 5`, in this case the `/` operator is the operator defined for the **int type** (because both sides are of **int type**) and so the result is an `int` too. Try this:

```
double  answer = 24 / 5.0;
Console.WriteLine("24 / 5 = " + answer);
```

When you provide one of the operands with a **double type**, in this case the double form of the `/` operator will be used and the result will be a double too.

Comment: Worked a treat! Any ideas why this wouldnt work when I used double variable on numbers but without the 5.0 (just 5)?

Comment: @Pixie.  5.0 isn't an integer so the result is a double.  5 and 24 are both integers which then triggers integer division

Comment: @Pixie: "I used double variables" -- well not really.  You stored the result in a double variable, but that was too late to affect the calculation.  If you had done `double x = 24, y = 5; double answer = x / y;` it would have worked.